# Angular @Input property - missing first value from array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a problem with sending values from one component to other. I've got 2 components: report-form and comment-form. Report form have an array of comments. It also show list of comment and button for each of them. After clicking a button It should load modal form with @Input property commentIndex. Problem is that report-form component don't send only(!) first value of array to comment-form. I don't have idea why :/.

Here's some code:

Part of report-form.html:

```
 <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-12 alert alert-dark">Komentarze:</div>
    <div class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let comment of comments">{{ comment.content }}
      <app-comment-form [commentIndex]="comments.indexOf(comment)"></app-comment-form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <app-comment-form></app-comment-form>
  </div>
```

If I log it on console in comment-form I've got 1,2 in 3 elements array but where's 0?!

Comment: Are you sure that your comments array has element on `0` index? Try to `console.log(this.comments[0])` in your controller.

Comment: You could use the `index` from the *ngFor in this case. `*ngFor="let comment of comments; let idx = index;"`

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure my array have element at index 0 and this tip didn't worked :(

Comment: `if (this.commentIndex)` will fail if `index` is `0` so, you can send `[commentIndex]="i + 1"`

Comment: Yeah, found it myself but I've got another problem because my values doesn't update in modal :/ only first element of array work :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use index provided by the `*ngFor` directly.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-12 alert alert-dark">Komentarze:</div>
    <div class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let comment of comments; let i = index">{{ comment.content }}
      <app-comment-form [commentIndex]="i"></app-comment-form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <app-comment-form></app-comment-form>
</div>
```

This `index` will start from 0.

Comment: Tried - same result

Comment: can you create a working plunker. The above code does not seem to have any issue :(

Comment: So, what you really want is a non-working plunker? *ba-dum tss*

Comment: That would help us to debug whats happening

Comment: I'm sorry that was just a joke :)

Comment: Ahh, you got me there :)

Comment: It seems that for TypeScript 0 === false, even if variable is number type and we are checking like that if(someVariable)

Comment: I had to change every where my if's to if(commentIndex >= 0) to work

Comment: glad you figured out